# Creating symlink for C:\Program Files

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Is it possible to create a symbolic link in Windows that redirects C:\Program Files to another drive?

Comment: Googling tells me that a NTFS junction should work, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Done this with 2 computers.

**mklink /j  Link Target**

Comment: How did you do this? I can't rename C:/Program Files and JunctionMaster tells me it is unable to reloacte C:/Program Files

Comment: @th3falc0n  You have to use a bootable DVD preferable the Windows 7 install DVD.(http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24394.iso)  Select **Repair** then **Command Prompt**.  **rename "Program Files" x** then **mklink /j "c:\Program Files" "d:\program files"**  Now use **xcopy /h /e /c c:\x\*.* "d:\Program Files\"**

Comment: .net framework installer detects that the relocation is on a different partition and refuses to install. it works for installer that do not want to be overly zealous about paranoid about checking everything and trying to be super-aware of stuff it doesn't have to be. (hint: this is what a bloated microsoft installer does)

Answer (score 0):

The safer, more flexible solution is to use "mklink /d link target". It will work with UNC paths as well, allowing you to install ALL your programs on a NAS device!